# Passing a variable defined in a function to NSTimer function objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm defining a variable in my function and trying to pass it to a nstimer. Is this possible? My concern is the function is removed from the callback stack and the variable no longer exists in memory (because we're waiting some time before we actually call anything on the parameters created in the prior method) Here's an example:

```
...
static NSTimer *oldTimer;

-(void)someFunction
{
    SKEmitterNode *left = [SKEmitterNode nodeWithFileNamed:leftParticle];

    if (oldTimer != nil)
    {
    [oldTimer invalidate];
    }

    oldTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:sec target:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) userInfo:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: left, nil] repeats:NO];
}

-(void)doSomething:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [[[timer userInfo] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromParent];
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this isn't possible? Did you get a compiler error? Did you try running the code?

Comment: Really sorry I realize how stupid the question sounds I just edited it.

Comment: No worries, just trying to understand. can you include the definition of olderTimer? Also, are you worried about the timer going out of memory or the NSArray for `userInfo`?

Comment: The timer should retain it's `userInfo` and be available inside `doSomething`. Is that not the case you've found when debugging?

Comment: Yess that's exactly what I needed to know. Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) for future reference, please run and debug your code a few times before posting on Stack Overflow, and present a problem rather than just a question. You'll get the most help that way. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Patrick Goley said, NSTimer retains the userInfo making it available inside of the selector method. Thanks again Patrick!